# Нужно ли отбивать пробелами знак плюс-минус между двумя числами?

Tags: пробелы

> Средний (±СО) возраст пациентов составил 41±12 лет.

Я полагаю, что первый знак отделять не нужно. Нужно ли отбивать пробелами второй знак? СО – стандартное отклонение.

Comment: Какой второй знак?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как правильно было сказано в другом ответе, пробел не нужен между знаком и следующим за ним числом. Но это касается отдельно стоящих чисел.

[**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)

> Пробелы нужны. Знаки математических **действий** и соотношений (+ , – , х , : , / , =) **отбивают** от смежных символов и чисел.

[**Пробелы, тире, дефисы, точки, цифры, кавычки, аббревиатуры, инициалы**](https://writercenter.ru/blog/grammar/probely-tire-defisy-tochki-cifry-kavychki-abbreviatury-inicialy.html)

> Бинарные знаки математических операций и соотношений **отбиваются** с обеих сторон:
>   2 + 3 = 5

[**Числа и знаки**](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091464.html)

> Числовое значение с допуском или с **предельными отклонениями** при сочетании с обозначением единицы физ. величины требуется заключить **в скобки** либо обозначение единицы поставить **и после** числового значения, **и после** допуска или предельного отклонения. Напр.:
>   Правильно: (10 ± 0,1) мм; 10 мм ± 0,1 мм
>   Неправильно: 10 ± 0,1 мм

Варианты:

*Средний (±СО) возраст пациентов составил (41 ± 12) лет.*

*Средний (±СО) возраст пациентов составил 41 год ± 12 лет.*

*Средний (±СО) возраст пациентов составил 41 год (±12 лет).*

Третий вариант, по моему мнению, выглядит предпочтительней: и буквенное (СО), и числовое (12) стандартное отклонение взято в скобки.

Первый вариант с точки зрения языка "не читается", поскольку 41 оканчивается на единицу и сочетается со словом "год".

Comment: Да, все правильно Вы пишете, поддерживаю. Вот примеры: Δmax = ±0,15 В (без пробела); U = (111,45 ± 0,15) В (численные значения в скобках, с пробелом). Есть еще один вариант оформления (мне он кажется самым оптимальным): Средний возраст пациентов составил 41 год (СО = ±12).

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Да, так тоже можно, спасибо, Римма. Я отталкивался от исходного предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно. Плюс и минус по отдельности не отбиваются, когда мы ставим плюс-минус, ничего не меняется.

[Вот](https://writercenter.ru/blog/grammar/probely-tire-defisy-tochki-cifry-kavychki-abbreviatury-inicialy.html) рекомендация:

> Плюс, минус и плюс-минус НЕ отбиваются от следующего за ним числа:
>   +20 °C, −42, **±0,1.**

Comment: Вы даёте ответ только для "(±СО)", так ведь? Потому что в случае "41±12 лет" требуется такая же отбивка, как и для любых бинарных операций, я думаю (в справочнике Мильчина, например, можно встретить подобные примеры).

Comment: @grizzly: нет, я в общем случае отвечаю.

Answer (score 0):

Математические знаки =, <, >, || и др. применяются лишь в формулах; в текстах пишутся слова: «равно», «параллельно», «больше» и др. Например:

> Производительность насоса *равна* 4 куб.м в час.

*(Редактирование научной книги. Е. С. Лихтенштейн, стр. 214)*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ваш случай: «Возраст пациентов составил 41 год плюс-минус 12 лет».

Comment: Извините, не согласен. Как можно представить себе статью или монографию, в которых сплошь и рядом используется статистика с цифрами с использованием математического разброса? Везде нужно писать словами?

Comment: Дайте ссылку, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5645884/ Этот учебник есть у меня, в цифре его не встречал.

Comment: Пример только подтверждает корректность записи "Возраст пациентов составил 41±12 лет". В примере записывается в виде формулы "4м^3", а затем формула вдруг обрывается и продолжается текстом "в час". Вместо того чтобы написать "равна 4 куб.м в час" либо "равна 4м^3/ч"

Comment: Что есть формула, помните? Формула – это всегда равенства. В какой формуле встречается слово «составил» или ему подобное? Отдельные знаки и символы не могут считаться формулой.

Comment: Хорошо. В вашей интерпретации примера получается "Возраст пациентов равен 41 ± 12 лет" корректная запись. А "Возраст пациентов составил 41 ± 12 лет" некорректная запись. Верно? Так и запишем в протоколе :) Я думаю автор имел ввиду другое

Comment: @user190920 Спасибо за подсказку, учёл. Насчёт взглядов автора ничего сказать не могу, он не высказывал своего отношения к обсуждаемому здесь.

Comment: Лихтенштейн в этом пункте говорит (без контекста сложно судить, насколько это неаккуратно) только о тех знаках, которые Мильчин называе "знаки равенства и соотношения между левой и правой частями формулы".

Comment: Может, этот пример Вас убедит: в добротной технической литературе миллионы раз встречаются выражения типа: "при температуре от +5 до –10°С" (и это точная цитата из Мильчина).

Comment: @grizzly 1. Автором я назвал задавшего вопрос (не понял user190920 ). 2. В вопросе приведена фраза-формула. Признак формулы — слово «составил» и две группы мат. символов и знаков по обе стороны от него. 3. В Вашем,  grizzly, выражении про t°С признака равенства или формулы нет, и оно само по себе не может быть не корректно.

Comment: Вы не понимаете, но это теперь не важно — уже появился правильный ответ.

Comment: @grizzly Рад буду за автора вопроса, когда кто-то ему укажет верное решение. Пока он молчит.